Start container only when previous container has run and stopped
I have a situation in which I will have four containers in my docker-compose file.
The second is dependent upon the first, and the third is dependent upon the second and fourth on third. But here is the catch, I want that the second should only start when the first has run , completed it's process and stopped. then the same for third and fourth. After the fourth container has run and completed it's process and stopped, the first should start agian, and the cycle continues.
Is their a way i can acheive this using docker-compose file?
Currently i havent found any solution on google.

Feels like it would be easier to handle this with a shell script that starts a container and if it successfully exits then starts the next one, and so on.

Compose doesn't support running containers in a loop.
Present-day Compose, using the "specification" version of the Compose file format, supports an extended depends_on: syntax that allows you to run a set of job-type containers in order.  Beyond that and setting a container to wait for a service-type container to be running, there's no other constraints or control flow possible in Compose.
That means you need some other way to run these containers.  A commenter suggested a shell script, and that would be easy enough
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
  docker run --rm first-image
  docker run --rm second-image
  docker run --rm third-image
  docker run --rm fourth-image
done

Combining these tasks into a single container, or even a single program, might make them easier to run.  Sometimes for a job runner it is easier and more portable to use a job-queueing system like RabbitMQ in combination with a long-running worker container; in this setup each job could enqueue the next job so things run in a loop.
